# need a 24c32 eeprom simple library, to read 1 page into a buffer, and write/transfer the buffer contents back to a selected page in the eeprom

Tags: eeprom

I need a simple program to read one page (user selected) from a 24c32 eeprom to a buffer of 32 bytes.

After the buffer data is manipulated, I want to write the buffer data back to the 24c32 page ( user selected).

I have been doing this with microcontrollers with great ease.

Somehow, I have not been successful on the Raspberry Pi pico.

My i2c routine for reading and writing time data to DS3231 is working fine on the Raspberry Pi pico board.

Somehow, I have not been successful on the Raspberry Pi pico for the 24c32.

Kindly help with an example micro python code.

Thanks in advance.

Vishwanath A

The DS3231 - rtc program for reading and writing time data ( max 8 bytes) is working fine.

But I am not able to get thru with the same logic for reading or writing 1 page of data.